# How to insert link in exported excel's cell using Ag-Grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid for showing grid data in my angular project. In HTML, some grid cell has links. But when I try to export the gird as excel ([Excel Export](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-excel/)), those links in the cell in excel are shown as plain text. So, my question is how can I insert hyperlink in excel from ag-grid data.

1. Is there any way of inserting formula in excel cell, eg: =HYPERLINK(<link_>, <text_to_show>) from ag-grid while exporting excel?
2. Can I render html in the excel cell so that the link can be inserted as anchor element tag from ag-grid?

Ag-grid data (in HTML):

[image]

I want same output in exported excel also where those links can be clickable.

N.B: I am using ag-grid enterprise product.
Thanks.

Comment: you can use =HYPERLINK(<link_>, <text_to_show>) to show link in the exported excel but the problem is 
1. it looks ugly.
2. it doesn't render as hyperlink unless you hit enter on that cell in excel.
3. it is visible in formula so it doesnt render like link type in excel.

doing the 2nd thing is even more difficult and you may need some other library to do this for you.

we ended up doing 1st thing in our project since end user was ok with hitting enter(not happy though).

Answer (score 1):

use `processCellCallback` function in export params to define your function which will create hyperlink in excel.

```
   {
       name: 'Excel Export (.xlsx)',
        action: function () { 
        params.exportMode = 'xlsx',
        params.processCellCallback = customProcessCellCallback
        return grid.exportDataAsExcel(params); 
              }
    },

    customProcessCellCallback = function (cell) {
            var cellVal = cell.value;
            if(check for link condition) {
                //make sure to handle empty undefined and null.
                if (cellVal === "" || cellVal === undefined || cellVal === null) {
                    cellVal = '';
                }
                else{
                cellVal = '=HYPERLINK("your link here","'+cellVal+'")';
                }
            }
            return cellVal;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, @sandeep. Thanks for your answer. I've tried this solution earlier. And you are right, it looks ugly and have to hit enter to look like a link. Maybe there are no other way to achieve  this. 

Comment: @ChinmoyAcharjee did you manage to find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the link to render (it should render immediately when you open Excel).

Assume the data for each row looks something like this:

```
{
    /* ... */
    myLinkColumnHref: "https://www.example.com/",
    myLinkColumn: "Example",
    /* ... */
}
```

**Step 1:** Set up your `processCellCallback` routine:

```
// Use the appropriate check in this if condition, this is just a sample
if(params.column.colDef.field == "myLinkColumn") {
    return `=HYPERLINK("${params.node.data.myLinkColumnHref}", "${params.value}")`;
}
```

In this example, I'm using the `myLinkColumnHref` data element, which might contain the HREF for the link. I'm also using the `params.value` element for the text of the link.

**Step 2:** Add the `autoConvertFormulas: true` option to the `defaultExcelExportParams` configuration (or to the configuration passed in to the export routine):

```
defaultExcelExportParams: {
    autoConvertFormulas: true,
    processCellCallback: { /* ... */ }
},
```